# Powershell Active Directory - Update a users `Initials` property

Tags: powershell, active-directory

*** COMPLETE REFRESH ***

I have made so many changes trying to figure this out, I decided to just refresh this question and post the entire script in hopes of finding a solution. I apologize for the length of the post. ANY info on what I am doing wrong would be a blessing. I have a lot of other stuff going on and keep circling back to this only to hit the same roadblocks. Thanks group!

With this current iteration, I am getting the following output/error now:

```
Transcript started, output file is C:\SftpRoot\loginid\logs\ou.log
Students OU already exists. Skipping...
ES OU already exists. Skipping...
1 OU already exists. Skipping...
2 OU already exists. Skipping...
3 OU already exists. Skipping...
4 OU already exists. Skipping...
NW OU already exists. Skipping...
1 OU already exists. Skipping...
2 OU already exists. Skipping...
3 OU already exists. Skipping...
4 OU already exists. Skipping...
SR OU already exists. Skipping...
1 OU already exists. Skipping...
2 OU already exists. Skipping...
3 OU already exists. Skipping...
4 OU already exists. Skipping...
EC OU already exists. Skipping...
PK OU already exists. Skipping...
K OU already exists. Skipping...
PI OU already exists. Skipping...
5 OU already exists. Skipping...
6 OU already exists. Skipping...
MS OU already exists. Skipping...
7 OU already exists. Skipping...
8 OU already exists. Skipping...
HS OU already exists. Skipping...
9 OU already exists. Skipping...
10 OU already exists. Skipping...
11 OU already exists. Skipping...
12 OU already exists. Skipping...

802.1x Staff Group already exists. Skipping...
802.1x Student Group already exists. Skipping...
Domain Admins Group already exists. Skipping...
Domain Users Group already exists. Skipping...
Importing the data. Can be long, please wait.


DistinguishedName : CN=Jon Doe,OU=11,OU=HS,OU=Students,DC=devdc,DC=com
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : Jon
Name              : Jon Doe
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : 1ef7e9b2-5e77-4dc7-8275-62a14271b8f9
SamAccountName    : 11506
SID               : S-1-5-21-1720126610-2895624269-3985084094-8087
Surname           : Doe
UserPrincipalName : 11506@devdc.com

Error!
UpdateUser : Error updating user: , 
At C:\SftpRoot\loginid\Student-Import-To-AD.ps1:234 char:13
+             UpdateUser $StudentParameters
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,UpdateUser
```

Here is the full script as of right now...

```
<# 
    Set our Preference Variables and
    create the transcript log
#>
$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
Stop-Transcript | Out-Null
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
Start-Transcript -path "C:\SftpRoot\loginid\logs\ou.log"

<#
    Adding old fallbacks just in case
#>
Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

<#
    VARIABLES

    Make all options easy to edit and maintain
#>
$CSVFilePath = "C:\SftpRoot\loginid\student-ad.csv"

$Schools = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{Name='ES';Id='105';Grades=@('1','2','3','4')}
    [pscustomobject]@{Name='NW';Id='120';Grades=@('1','2','3','4')}
    [pscustomobject]@{Name='SR';Id='115';Grades=@('1','2','3','4')}
    [pscustomobject]@{Name='EC';Id='130';Grades=@('PK','K')}
    [pscustomobject]@{Name='PI';Id='125';Grades=@('5','6')}
    [pscustomobject]@{Name='MS';Id='510';Grades=@('7','8')}
    [pscustomobject]@{Name='HS';Id='705';Grades=@('9','10','11','12')}
)

$Groups = '802.1x Staff','802.1x Student','Domain Admins','Domain Users' # Add Groups in that the students should be added to.
$SubDomain = 'student' # SubDomain is used for email only.

<#
    Name: SchoolName
    Params: $schoolID

    Instructions: Call function and pass a school ID 
    in order to get the readable name.
#>
Function SchoolName {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [int] $passedID
    )
    switch($passedID) {
        130{return "EC"}
        105{return "ES"}
        115{return "SR"}
        120{return "NW"}
        125{return "PI"}
        510{return "MS"}
        705{return "HS"}
    }
} # END SchoolName

<#
    Name: GradeLevel
    Params: $passedID

    Instructions: Call function and pass a grade level 
    in order to get the readable name.
#>
Function GradeLevel {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [string] $passedID
    )
    switch($passedID) {
        "0"{return "K"}
        "-1"{return "PK"}
        default{return "$passedID"}
    }
} # END GradeLevel

<#
    Name: CreateOUs
    Params: NA

    Instructions: Call function to verify and create 
    Organizational Units in AD.
#>
Function CreateOUs() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    # Create Inner Variables
    $DomainPath = 'DC='+$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Substring(0,$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Length-4).ToLower()+',DC='+$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Substring($env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Length-3).ToLower()

    if(![adsi]::Exists("LDAP://OU=Students,$DomainPath")){New- ADOrganizationalUnit Students -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $True; Write-Host "Students OU being created." -foregroundcolor Green}else{Write-Host "Students OU already exists. Skipping..." -foregroundcolor Yellow}

    # Check for the schools OU paths
    $Schools | ForEach-Object {
        $SchoolPath = "OU=Students,$DomainPath"
        $SchoolName = $_.'Name'

        if(![adsi]::Exists("LDAP://OU=$SchoolName,$SchoolPath")){New-ADOrganizationalUnit $SchoolName -Path $SchoolPath -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $False; Write-Host "$SchoolName OU being created." -foregroundcolor Green}else{Write-Host "$SchoolName OU already exists. Skipping..." -foregroundcolor Yellow}

        $GradePath = "OU=$SchoolName,$SchoolPath"
    
        ForEach($Grade in $_.'Grades'){
            if(![adsi]::Exists("LDAP://OU=$Grade,$GradePath")){New-ADOrganizationalUnit $Grade -Path $GradePath -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $False; Write-Host "$Grade OU being created." -foregroundcolor Green}else{Write-Host "$Grade OU already exists. Skipping..." -foregroundcolor Yellow}
        }
    }

} CreateOUs # END CreateOUs

<#
    Name: CreateGroups
    Params: NA

    Instructions: Call function to verify and create 
    Organizational Groups in AD.
#>
Function CreateGroups {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    # Check for and create the Groups in the provided array above
    $Groups | ForEach-Object {
        # Create Path variable
        $gPath = 'CN=Users,DC='+$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Substring(0,$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Length-4).ToLower()+',DC='+$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Substring($env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Length-3).ToLower()
        $gName = $_

        if(![adsi]::Exists("LDAP://CN=$gName,$gPath")){New-ADGroup -GroupCategory "Security" -GroupScope "Global" -Name "$gName" -Path "$gPath" -SamAccountName "$gName"; Write-Host "$gName Group is being created." -foregroundcolor Green}else{Write-Host "$gName Group already exists. Skipping..." -foregroundcolor Yellow}
    }
} CreateGroups # END CreateGroups

<#
    Name: CreateUser
    Params: [array]PassedUser

    Instructions: Call function and pass in a User object 
    which has all values needed to create New-ADUser.
#>
Function CreateUser {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [array] $PassedUser
    )
    try {
        New-ADUser @PassedUser
    } catch {
        Write-Error "Error creating user: $($PassedUser.lname), $($PassedUser.fname)"
    }
} # END CreateUser

<#
    Name: UpdateUser
    Params: [array]PassedUser

    Instructions: Call function and pass in a User object 
    which has all values needed to update Set-ADUser.
#>
Function UpdateUser {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [array]$PassedUser
    )
    try {
        Get-ADUser -Identity $($PassedUser.SamAccountName) | `
        Set-ADUser -Identity $($PassedUser.SamAccountName) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False -Description "$($user.studentID)" -DisplayName "$($user.lname+", "+$user.fname)" -Mail "$($StudentEmail)" -Enabled $True -GivenName "$($user.fname)" -PasswordNeverExpires $True -SamAccountName "$($user.studentID)" -Surname "$($user.lname)" -UserPrincipalName "$($user.studentID+"@"+$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.ToLower())"
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error!" -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Error "Error updating user: $($PassedUser.lname), $($PassedUser.fname)"
    }
} # END UpdateUser

<#
    Begin the real work here. 
    Above is variable declarations and 
    building operations for the AD-Groups
    and the AD-OUs.
#>
#Store the data from Users.csv in the $Users variable
Write-Host 'Importing the data. Can be long, please wait.'
If ([System.IO.File]::Exists($CSVFilePath)) {

    $Users = Import-csv $CSVFilePath `
        -Header lname, fname, mname, studentID, gradeLevel, schoolID
    
    #$Users |
    #Select *, @{Name='schoolName';Expression={SchoolName $_.schoolID}} | `
    #Select *, @{Name='actualGrade';Expression={GradeLevel $_.gradeLevel}} | `
    #Sort-Object -Property "schoolID", "gradeLevel", "lname", "fname", "mname"
            
    foreach($user in $Users) {
        <# 
            Check for inclusion of a Middle Name.
            Build appropriate variables needed.
        #>
        $HasMiddleName = ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($user.mname)

        If ($HasMiddleName) {
            $global:Password = ($user.fname.substring(0,1) + $user.mname.substring(0,1) + $user.lname.substring(0,1) + $user.studentID)
            $global:MiddleInitial = $user.mname.substring(0,1)
        }else{
            $global:Password = ($user.fname.substring(0,1) + $user.lname.substring(0,1) + $user.studentID)
            $global:MiddleInitial = $Null
        }

        <#
            Check for inclusion of a SubDomain.
            Build out appropriate variables needed.
        #>
        If (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($SubDomain)){
            $global:StudentEmail = ($user.studentID+"@"+$SubDomain+"."+$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Substring(0,$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Length-4).ToLower()+"."+$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Substring($env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Length-3).ToLower())
        } else {
            $global:StudentEmail = ($user.studentID+"@"+$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Substring(0,$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Length-4).ToLower()+"."+$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Substring($env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Length-3).ToLower())
        }

        <#
            Check for existing user.
            Either update an existing or create a new
        #>
        try {
            Get-ADUser -Identity $user.studentID
            # Account exists. Update name fields.
            $StudentParameters = @{
                ChangePasswordAtLogon = $False
                Description = "$($user.studentID)"
                DisplayName = "$($user.lname+", "+$user.fname)"
                Mail = "$($StudentEmail)"
                Enabled = $True
                GivenName = "$($user.fname)"
                PasswordNeverExpires = $True
                SamAccountName = "$($user.studentID)"
                Surname = "$($user.lname)"
                UserPrincipalName = "$($user.studentID+"@"+$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.ToLower())"
            }

            # Set trouble properties this way instead.
            if( ($Null -ne $MiddleInitial) -and ("" -ne $MiddleInitial) ) {
                $StudentParameters.Add("Initials", "$MiddleInitial")
            }
            
            UpdateUser $StudentParameters
        } catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityResolutionException] {
            # Account does NOT exist. Create new user.
            $StudentParameters = @{
                ChangePasswordAtLogon = $False
                Description = $($user.studentID)
                DisplayName = ($user.lname+", "+$user.fname)
                EmailAddress = $($StudentEmail)
                Enabled = $True
                GivenName = $($user.fname)
                Name = $($user.studentID)
                PasswordNeverExpires = $True
                Path = "OU=$user.actualGrade,OU=$user.schoolName,OU=Students,DC="+$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Substring(0,$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Length-4).ToLower()+",DC="+$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Substring($env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Length-3).ToLower()
                SamAccountName = S($user.studentID)
                Surname = $($user.lname)
                UserPrincipalName = ($user.studentID+"@"+$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.ToLower())
            }

            # Set trouble properties this way instead.
            if( ($Null -ne $MiddleInitial) -and ("" -ne $MiddleInitial) ) {
                $StudentParameters.Add("Initials", "$MiddleInitial")
            }

            CreateUser $StudentParameters
        }
    }
}

<#
    Let's wrap it up now!!!

    Give the date (should be the same)
    and stop the transcript log. 
#>
# Log the date
Get-Date

# Stop the transcript log
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: `Set-ADUser -Initials <string>` or `Set-ADUser @{Initials = 'string'}`

Comment: Could it be that every other param has a value and `Initials` may sometimes be blank?  Just a thought.
Isn't the `$($MiddleInitial)` dereference redundant?  There is no dot operator, so just `$MiddleInitial` should suffice.  Same with `$StudentEmail`

Comment: @jswanson Yes. That is probably it, but that is why I actually test for a middle initial ahead of time using the added code to the OP under 'MIDDLE INITIAL'. How else would I process that if it is possibly blank.

Comment: TL;DR; Change `@StudentParameters` to `$StudentParameters` (maybe?). From the error message `UpdateUser @StudentParameters ` it looks like you are trying to splat $StudentParameters and it probably contains properties that don't line up with your function arguments.  If you splat (use `@` instead of `$`) it will take the properties and use them them as parameters and arguments.  Your `UpdateUser` function only has one parameter `-PassedUser`, not '-Initials` or any of those other properties in `$StudentParameters`

Comment: Of course you are going to get the same error, you are still splatting StudentParameters...  `UpdateUser @StudentParameters` needs to be changed to `UpdateUser $StudentParameters`.   Stop splatting (see my answer and update both lines where you are splatting) and then implement @mclayton answer

Comment: @Daniel negative. I changed it. No longer splatting. In fact, I broke it out completely like an array rather than an object or splat.

`Get-ADUser -Identity $($PassedUser.SamAccountName) | Set-ADUser -Identity $($PassedUser.SamAccountName) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False -Description "$($user.studentID)" -DisplayName "$($user.lname+", "+$user.fname)" -Mail "$($StudentEmail)" -Enabled $True -GivenName "$($user.fname)" -PasswordNeverExpires $True -SamAccountName "$($user.studentID)" -Surname "$($user.lname)" -UserPrincipalName "$($user.studentID+"@"+$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.ToLower())"`

Comment: @Daniel calling it like this now: 

`UpdateUser $StudentParameters`

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You might be hitting this issue with the `-Replace` parameter from the [Set-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2019-ps) documentation:

> -Replace
>
> Specifies values for an object property that will replace the current values. Use this parameter to replace one or more values of a property that cannot be modified using a cmdlet parameter. To modify an object property, you must use the LDAP display name. You can specify multiple values to a property by specifying a comma-separated list of values, and more than one property by separating them using a semicolon.
>
> **If any of the properties have a null or empty value the cmdlet will return an error**.
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

In which case the solution might be to not include the `Initials` key in the `$StudentParameters` hashtable if it's `$null` or en empty string - e.g.:

```
$StudentParameters = @{
    ... etc ...
    # Initials = $($MiddleInitial) # <---- remove this line
    ... etc ...
};

# set the property this way instead...
if( ($null -ne $MiddleInitial) -and ("" -ne $MiddleInitial) )
{
    $StudentParameters.Add("Initials", $MiddleInitial);
}
```

This will probably also extend to all the other properties as well - e.g. `GivenName = $($user.fname)` but maybe they're never `$null` so you've not hit the problem on those properties before...

**Update**

If you want to extend the above pattern to all your properties, it might be cleaner to build the hashtable how you’re already doing it and then *remove* the null keys in a for loop before you call `Set-ADUser`...

```
# remove parameters that would break -Replace
foreach( $key in @($StudentParameters.Keys) )
{
    if( $null -eq $StudentParameters[$key] )
    {
         $StudentParameters.Remove($key)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution - all your 'Replace' parameters must have values if they exist. And also, when using a splat function, yes, use the ldap names of the properties to avoid any confusion.  To check whether `$middleInitial` is populated, I prefer to keep it simple - `If ($middleInitial) ( $studentParameters.Add() ... }`  - works with empty string and undefined property (not tested with <=PS 2.0 )

Comment: @LeeM - I think @Daniel may have actually spotted the root issue causing OP’s error. - splatting into UpdateUser, but I suspect they’ll hit the ```-Replace``` issue as soon as they’ve fixed that one :-).

Comment: Ok, I removed the `Initials` key both ways. I had actually tried that already, but wanted to try again to ensure it wasn't a different error given. Same error when the value is present. 

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

You cannot splat `@StudentParameters` into parameters/arguments for `Function UpdateUser`.  Essentially what splatting is doing is this:

```
UpdateUser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False -Description $($user.studentID) `
-DisplayName ($user.lname+", "+$user.fname) -Mail $($StudentEmail) `
-Enabled $True -GivenName  $($user.fname) -Initials  $($MiddleInitial) `
-PasswordNeverExpires  $True -SamAccountName  $($user.studentID) `
-Surname $($user.lname) -UserPrincipalName ($user.studentID+"@"+$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.ToLower())
```

The UpdateUser function has none of these parameters.  Initials just happens to be the first one it encounters and errors on.  It says exactly this in the error message.

```
UpdateUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Initials'.
 
At C:\SftpRoot\loginid\Student-Import-To-AD.ps1:287 char:28  
+                 UpdateUser @StudentParameters  
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [UpdateUser], ParameterBindingException  
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,UpdateUser
```

Just pass your hashtable in as usual

```
UpdateUser $StudentParamenters
```

Then you also want to change this inside your function

```
Function UpdateUser {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [PSObject[]]$PassedUser
    )
    try {
        # -Replace is expecting a hashtable so provide it as-is, do not splat (@) here either
        Get-ADUser -Identity $($PassedUser.studentID) | Set-ADUser -Replace $PassedUser
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Error updating user: $($PassedUser.lname), $($PassedUser.fname)"
    }
} # END UpdateUser
```

**Update**

Updated UpdateUser function and put it all together including changes recommended by mclayton.  <strike>I coded it a little differently because I had trouble using it exactly as mclayton suggested (could not modify the hashtable while it was being enumerated)</strike> (fixed.  Thank you mclayton)

```
<#
    Name: UpdateUser
    Params: [PSObject[]]User

    Instructions: Call function and pass in a User object
    which has all values needed to update Set-ADUser.
#>
Function UpdateUser {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [PSObject[]]$PassedUser
    )

    # Add mclaytons suggestions to not include empty/null values 
    # remove parameters that would break -Replace
    foreach( $key in @($PassedUser.Keys) )
    {
        if( $null -eq $PassedUser[$key] )
        {
             $PassedUser.Remove($key)
        }
    }
    
    try {
        # Use $PassedUser hashtable which has been stripped of empty values
        # KEEP -Replace parameter and pass in $PassedUser hashtable
        Get-ADUser -Identity $($PassedUser.studentID) | Set-ADUser -Replace $PassedUser
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Error updating user: $($PassedUser.lname), $($PassedUser.fname)"
    }
} # END UpdateUser

<#
        Check for existing user.
        Either update an existing or create a new
    #>
try {
    Get-ADUser -Identity $user.studentID
    # Account exists. Update name fields.
    $StudentParameters = @{
        ChangePasswordAtLogon = $False
        Description           = $($user.studentID)
        DisplayName           = ($user.lname + ', ' + $user.fname)
        Mail                  = $($StudentEmail)
        Enabled               = $True
        GivenName             = $($user.fname)
        Initials              = $($MiddleInitial)
        PasswordNeverExpires  = $True
        SamAccountName        = $($user.studentID)
        Surname               = $($user.lname)
        UserPrincipalName     = ($user.studentID + '@' + $env:USERDNSDOMAIN.ToLower())
    }

    # DO NOT SPLAT StudentParameters!!
    UpdateUser $StudentParameters
}
catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityResolutionException] {
    # Account does NOT exist. Create new user.
    $StudentParameters = @{
        ChangePasswordAtLogon = $False
        Description           = $($user.studentID)
        DisplayName           = ($user.lname + ', ' + $user.fname)
        EmailAddress          = $($StudentEmail)
        Enabled               = $True
        GivenName             = $($user.fname)
        Initials              = $($MiddleInitial)
        Name                  = $($user.studentID)
        PasswordNeverExpires  = $True
        Path                  = "OU=$user.actualGrade,OU=$user.schoolName,OU=Students,DC=" + $env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Substring(0, $env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Length - 4).ToLower() + ',DC=' + $env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Substring($env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Length - 3).ToLower()
        SamAccountName        = S($user.studentID)
        Surname               = $($user.lname)
        UserPrincipalName     = ($user.studentID + '@' + $env:USERDNSDOMAIN.ToLower())
    }
    CreateUser @StudentParameters
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Some helpful info in there. I also thought the same and have tried this too though. It still finds `Initials` and errors though.

As you can see, the `Initial` shows up and outputs prior to the call. It still doesn't like `Initials`.
T...
UpdateUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Initials'.`

Comment: @daniel - “could not modify the hashtable while it was being enumerated” - ah, yeah, sorry - I was shooting from the hip typing it on my iPhone so couldn’t try it live :-). You could probably do ```foreach( $key in @($StudentParameters.Keys) )``` to avoid the enumeration error as well.

Comment: @mclayton, no worries!  I know how that is.  Nice fix by the way.  Updated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the hash table of params can be in any order, you can build the bulk of it as you have it and then deal with the problem params afterward.

```
$StudentParameters = @{
    ChangePasswordAtLogon = $False
    Description = $($user.studentID)
    DisplayName = ($user.lname+", "+$user.fname)
    Mail = $($StudentEmail)
    Enabled = $True
    GivenName = $($user.fname)
    # Initials = $($MiddleInitial)
    PasswordNeverExpires = $True
    SamAccountName = $($user.studentID)
    Surname = $($user.lname)
    UserPrincipalName = ($user.studentID+"@"+$env:USERDNSDOMAIN.ToLower())
}
# mname property may be blank, so only add the parameter if nonblank
if ($user.mname) {
  # append a line to the hash table
  $StudentParameters += @{Initials = $user.mname}  
}
UpdateUser @StudentParameters
```

If you prefer not to use the simple conditional test `if ($user.mname)` then replace with whatever you are comfortable with. It works well for string variables in my experience.